# Appfuse app velocity error while deploying on cloudbees

Tags: appfuse

I have appfuse stuts app when I deploy it on cloudbees I get below errors. I have bound database to the application in cloudbees. Are following errors due to JPA annotations or not getting connected to the DB?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.my.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.my.dao.UserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.my.model.User
    at

And  :
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.my.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.my.dao.UserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.my.model.User

Also
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] VelocityMenuDisplayer.initialize(73) | Error initializing Velocity: Error initializing log: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.
org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: Error initializing log: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.